# Creating a simple design in java using GrigBagLayout without using swing

Tags: java, awt, gridbaglayout

I want to create this design using only GrigBagLayout without using swing and panel in this code.

[image: 1]

Inorder to complete my assignment problem i just prepare the code for this this design but it is not perfectly arranged.

```
import java.awt.*;
class GridBagLayout {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Frame f = new Frame();
        f.setSize(400,600);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        Label l = new Label("Name  ");
        gbc.gridx=1;        
        gbc.gridy=1;
        f.add(l,gbc);


        TextField t = new TextField();
        gbc.gridx=1;            
        gbc.gridy=0;
        f.add(t,gbc);


        Label l2 = new Label("Password ");
        gbc.gridx=0;                    
        gbc.gridy=1;
        f.add(l2,gbc);

        TextField t2 = new TextField();
         gbc.gridx=1;           
         gbc.gridy=1;
        f.add(t2,gbc);


        Button b = new Button("OK");
        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.gridy=1;
        f.add(b,gbc);

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So anyone can tell me about where my code is lacking to perfectly arranged.

Comment: What do you mean by "perfectly arranged"? Anyway I think this would be better suited for this site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please define "perfectly arranged" and also what you get instead. Also, why not use Swing?

Comment: Btw, "using GridBagLayout" and `f.setLayout(new GridLayout());` don't match - I'm missing a bag there.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj sir I mean to say I want this design as I https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvS7t.jpg

Comment: "I want this design as I draw" - imo your drawing isn't perfectly arranged either ;) Seriously: you show us what you want but you don't show us what you get and ask why you don't get the desired results. How are we supposed to help if we don't know what the problem is other than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @Thomas I am learning java awt currently , I know nothing about swing

Comment: Well, I'd not even bother learning Swing anymore since it isn't actively maintained by Oracle and has basically been replaced by JavaFX. It's your choice though.

Comment: Another note: don't reuse the same instance of `GridBagConstraints` but provide a fresh instance for each component. Otherwise they'll all use the same constraints (that should already be covered by the Java basics - if not please revisit those before diving head first into UI)

Comment: @ Thomas sir I know but this is my assignment question which I have to done without swing..

Comment: @Thomas using new instance GridBagConstraints for each component but the problem still remains same

Comment: I also noted that you're using GridLayout not GridBagLayout. Besides that it is _hard_ to help without knowing the actual problem (your description is like "I want a red car but mine isn't - how can I change that?" - without knowing the current state of affairs it's often just guess work and our time is too valuable for that).

Comment: DYM something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAgwz.png)? Your drawing seems to align the labels to the left, but I think they are better aligned to the right, next to the text fields. BTW - you'll likely need to use a modal `java.awt.Dialog` for this, which will cause the code to pause at the line the dialog is set visible. The very next line of code, we can assume the user has put in the details and the app can get values from the fields.

Comment: *"manage the size of text field"* The easiest way is to use [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/TextField.html#<init>(int)) which accepts an integer number of columns (characters) for the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I hope your Assignment work should be based on GridBagLayout
>
> ### GridBagLayout
>
> so why you are using

- f.setLayout(new GridLayout());

> 

### *Instead of using correct Layout*

> f.setLayout(new GridBagLayout);

```
import java.awt.*;
    class GridBagLayout
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Frame f=new Frame();
            f.setSize(300,200);
            GridBagLayout gl = new GridBagLayout();
            f.setLayout(gl);
            GridBagConstraints g=new GridBagConstraints();
            g.gridx=0;
            g.gridy=0;
            f.add(new Label("Name") , g);

            g.gridy=1;
            f.add(new Label("Password") , g);

            g.gridx=1;
            g.gridy=0;
            f.add(new TextField(15) , g);

            g.gridy=1;
            g.gridx=1;
            f.add(new TextField(15) , g);       

            g.gridx=0;
            g.gridy=2;
            g.gridwidth=2;
            g.insets = new Insets(30,0,0,0);
            f.add(new Button("OK"),g);

            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

> > As GridBagLayout divides a container into a grid of equally sizwd cells and it requires lot of information to know where to put a
> >     component that's why i used gridx/y ,insets etc  for proper
> >     arrangements of your labels and texfields.

[Make your basics strong about java awt concepts ][1]

> [1]:
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html